# How to read a csv in python with a cell that contains only null characters (^@)

Tags: python, csv, special-characters

I have a `.csv` file that I cannot change. The rows are processed by python using the `csv` library.

One of the rows contains a cell which Vim has showed as `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` special characters. It looks similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

pd.DataFrame({
        'col0' : ['xxx', 'yyy', '^@^@^@^@', 'zzz'], 
        'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'col2' : ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
   }).to_csv('data.csv')

with open('data.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for n in range(3):
        row = next(reader)
        print(row[3])
```

When the reader arrives to the row containing special characters, even in the field referenced (e.g. 3) does not contain special characters, it returns `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I have tried opening the reader with different formats or encodings, and specifying the newline character as `newline=''` but the result is always the same.

Is there any way to deal with this sort of special characters?

Thanks

Comment: you can check if df.isnull().values.any().

Comment: @Mirza715 it is not a dataframe, the row gets loaded as a list. The moment it loads, returns: `Error: line contains NULL byte`

Comment: This is because of next(reader) reading null. You can do this, if next(reader): row = next(reader)

Comment: Yes. Right now I handle it with try: except: pass. But I want to know if there is any way to process that row and the values on the other cells, or is just a lost row.